# Passing Key-Value Array AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an key value pair array which I need to send to another function through ajax. My array looks something like this

```
       var vitals=new Array();
       var vitals["height"]=170; 
       var vitals["weight"]=55;
```

the ajax function is

```
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: url, // Location of the service
    data: JSON.stringify({ccdEntity: vitals }), //Data sent to server
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true, //True or False
    success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    }
```

and the function receiving the value is

```
  public bool GenerateCcd( Array ccdEntity)
```

when I run the program the function does not display the array with key-values but when I transfer a normal array (i.e) vitals[0]=170, it works fine . Do I need to make an changes for sending the above data to function?

Edit:
Tried passing the above array as a JSON object

```
             var vitals= {
        "height": "170",
        "weight": "55"}
```

but results still the same

Comment: Change the `vitals` declaration to be `var vitals = {};`. That way you can correctly use a key/value pair structure. Using an array, you were setting properties that aren't serialized. An object (`{}`) is really what you're looking for

Comment: @Ian Thanx for the reply.Tried that change but values still not getting passed.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this::

```
function TestAjax() {
    var vitals= [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        vitals.push({ Height: (170+i), Weight: (55+i) });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify( {vitals: vitals}),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Succeded");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP do that? What is the problem and how does your code solve it? **Explain** your solution!

Comment: Here User want a Solution with [Key,Value] pair Array,
and in my given solution the pair is made on the basis of: [height,weight]
which is passed to the Server side in the array[key,value] format.

@FelixKling Just have a look on my Edited code.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the explanation.

Comment: @FelixKling Just go through the solution that I have Provided.
If the guy asking question won't understand then he/she should ask for explanations..

Comment: @ Rahul RJ edited my code to add this line var vitals[];  vitals.push({ Height: 170 ,Weight:55}); when I check the value in the generateCCD function with breakpoint it shows the value of ccdEntity an {object} and does not display its contents. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `vitals` an object array rather than an array;;

```
   var vitals={'height': '170', 'weight': '55'};
```

And post your data like:

```
data: JSON.stringify(vitals)
```

Comment: Tried this method but values are not getting passed. Thanx anyways:)